# Pidgin "Send screenshot" plugin

Tags: 14.04, software-center, 64-bit, pidgin, screenshot

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (x64) with Pidgin 2.10.9 (libpurple 2.10.9) and I cannot install "Send screenshot" plugin from .deb package on it'[official site](https://code.google.com/p/pidgin-sendscreenshot/). If I try to, Software Center notifies me about bad package quality:

```
Lintian check results for /home/justlogin/Downloads/pidgin-sendscreenshot-0.8-3-amd64.deb:
Skipping /home/justlogin/Downloads/pidgin-sendscreenshot-0.8-3-amd64.deb: syntax error at line 18: Continuation line outside a paragraph (maybe line 17 should be " .").
```

Even when I choose "Ignore and install option", installation fails.

How can I add this plugin to Pidgin after all?